# Using SqlDependency in WCF Class Library project hosted as Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, sqldependency

I have created a notification service using `SqlDependency` for notifying other services about the change in a particular table. This is done in the Windows Service template from Visual Studio. Hence in the `OnStart` event, subscription of `SqlDependency` is created, and during `OnStop` event, un-subscription is done.

The above solution is working perfectly fine.

Now, due to some reasons, I have to make this a WCF class library project and host it as a Windows service. I couldn't think of a place where the subscription and un-subscription of `SqlDependency` can be done in such case.

When the Windows service is started, the subscription has to be done automatically.

Note: I have a generic Windows service host, which will host all my WCF class library project and can't do much there.

Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Does your generic windows service host implement OnStop signalling in some form or respect IDisposable?

Comment: Does my answer satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I got your problem right. You have all the logic inside of WCF library but don't know how to sync your subscribe and unsubscribe to SqlDependancy events on Windows Service start-up that will host your WCF service.

My idea is to use a ServiceHostFactory to create an instance of your service and hook on opening and closing events of your service, calling all necessary constructors and connectors from there.

I based most of my answer from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic4) great and lengthy article about hosting WCF services, with link pointing directly to the topic in your case. Some additional docs on [ServiceHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicehost?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [ServiceHostFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory?view=netframework-4.7.2) classes.

Bear in mind that this is not a complete code that you can just copy/paste but rather a demonstration of usage.

Here is an example of your Windows service:

```
public partial class YourWindowsService : ServiceBase
{

    // It's your choice where to create this instance, I used constructor injection here arbitrarily
    private readonly YourWCFServiceFactory serviceFactory;   

    private ServiceHost host;

    public YourWindowsService(YourWCFServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Type serviceType = typeof(YourService);
        host = serviceFactory.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, new string[] { "yourBaseUri" });
        host.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if(host != null)
           host.Close();
    }
}
```

And an example of your factory:

```
public class YourWCFServiceFactory: ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        ServiceHost host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        host.Opening += new EventHandler(host_Opening);
        host.Closing += new EventHandler(host_Closing);
        return host;
    }

    private void host_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialization here
    }

    private void host_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cleanup here
    }
}
```